# 51% attack on New coins

Tags: altcoin, majority-attack

I have experienced 51% attack after launching a new altcoin last month.

While i mined only 100 blocks using `coin-cli generate 1`, i noticed somebody already mined 2000 blocks within minutes attacking my network. I was running 2 nodes (without wallet) and 1 node (with wallet installed) in Ubuntu server.

- Why would the attacker target new cryptocurrencies? Is he after coins?
- What changes in the code i have to implement to prevent the 51% attack?

My altcoin is based on scrypt (litecoin), Block generation time is 10 minutes/hour, Coin maturity 100 blocks, with parameters almost same as bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would the attacker target new cryptocurrencies?

Why not? He has the same reasons as you to create blocks

> What changes in the code i have to implement to prevent the 51% attack?

Disable decentralization. Allow mining from one pubkey/address only :)

Comment: Where in the code i implement allow mining from one pubkey and address?

Comment: It's not a serious suggestion.

Comment: It is serious. I have to say that it is ONLY choice. No other suggestions can prevent attack-51 in any crypto